# How do you cure rabbit fur for an arrow rest?

Tags: archery, bow-hunting, tanning

I have a couple of recurve bows that my brother and I had when we were kids.  My kids are just starting to use them now, but the rabbit fur that my dad glued to the risers to use as arrow rests fell apart immediately when we started shooting them after 30 years of non-use.  I would like to replace the rests as close to the way my dad had it rigged as possible.  What is the best way to cure a small section of rabbit fur?  I would rather not go buy any tanning supplies for such a small project if possible.  I am also mostly interested in restoring the bows to the way I remember them, not finding the best arrow rest possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tanned some hides before. I believe you want to do only half the process otherwise you lose the fur.

Basically, you flay the animal (remove the skin). Then wash all the blood and stuff. Get it nice and clean and let it dry. I found direct sun dried is better. Also, if you can tie it up really stretched it will be better.

It's not a very complex process but you need to keep an eye to see how it goes. It's kind of like cooking, after you get the idea you know when it's good. Practice takes you to perfection. :)

Comment: I followed this (mostly) and got what appears to be a pretty good result.  The only thing I had to change was that I couldn't sun dry the pelt here in the rainy Northwest, so I put it in the food dehydrator overnight, then tumbled it in the dryer to soften it up a bit.  So far so good.  Thanks!

Comment: Nice. The key thing is not to damage the fur. The idea of the food dehy is also clever... and funny. :)